# Match and highlight documents using different queries for different fields in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

My objective is to create a query which will find the "best" 20 documents using a normal `query_string` query on fields A, B, and C of a document and trying to do an exact or exact-subset match on field D. For example: if field D is 'AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD' then queries for "AAA.BBB" should match (and "BBB.CCC", and "AAA.BBB.CCC", etc). Oh yeah, I'd also like to have the highlighted results.

My closest attempt to date is to use an ngram tokenizer/analyzer on field D and just allowing A, B, C to be indexed as normal.

```
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 5,
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "tokenizer": {
                    "customNgram": {
                        "type": "nGram",
                        "min_gram": "3",
                        "max_gram": "5"
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "lllNgram": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "filter": "lowercase",
                        "tokenizer": "customNgram"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "lessons": {
            "_id": {
                "path": "id"
            },
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "A": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "yes"
                },
                "B": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "yes"
                },
                "C": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "yes"
                },
                "D": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "yes",
                    "analyzer": "lllNgram"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then using a query like so:

```
{
    "size":20,
    "query":{
        "filtered":{
            "query":{
                "match_all":{}
            },
            "filter":{
                "or":[
                    {
                        "query":{
                            "query_string":{
                                "query":"XYZZY TOP",
                                "fields":["A","B","C"]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "query":{
                            "match":{
                                "D": {
                                    "query":"XYZZY TOP",
                                    "operator" : "and"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
         }
    },
    "highlight":{
        "pre_tags":["<em>"],
        "post_tags":["<\/em>"],
        "fields":{
            "A":{},
            "B":{},
            "C":{},
            "D":{}
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that field D seems to never match anything... ever... no matter what. The resultset also does not contain any highlighting with this query.

SO, please help me to understand what I have done wrong in my query.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There're a couple of issues in your mapping/query:

- Wrong ngram size: you define `ngram(3, 5)`, so maximum of length for generated terms is only 5, and you query for `AAA.BBB` (length=7). It can match in your mapping, but it's ineffective and it's a wrong design in this case (wrong in using it for both indexing and searching), you can extend it to `ngram(3, 20)` and use it just for indexing time.
- Ineffective mapping: you dont need to define ngram for both indexing/searching. Instead you can define `index_analyzer = lllNgram`, then use an analyzer that not modify the data for search_analyzer, eg `search_analyzer = keyword_lowercase_analyzer` in my example. `index_analyzer` is used when indexing data, so we need to define rules to generate all possible terms to match (ngram in this case), `search_analyzer` is used when parsing query before comparing with indexed data, so we just need to define rule to keep it as original in this case (just lowercase it)
- Inconsequence query: why did you have to use a filtered query ? It'll omit the ES scores and you can't get `the "best" 20 documents` results.

Here's a workable mapping/query:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 5,
        "index": {
            "analysis": {
                "tokenizer": {
                    "customNgram": {
                        "type": "nGram",
                        "min_gram": "3",
                        "max_gram": "20"
                    }
                },
                "analyzer": {
                    "lllNgram": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "filter": "lowercase",
                        "tokenizer": "customNgram"
                    },
                    "keyword_lowercase_analyzer": {
                        "tokenizer": "keyword",
                        "filter": ["lowercase"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "lessons": {
            "_id": {
                "path": "id"
            },
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "A": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "yes"
                },
                "B": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "yes"
                },
                "C": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "yes"
                },
                "D": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": "yes",
                    "index" : "analyzed",
                    "index_analyzer" : "lllNgram",
                    "search_analyzer" : "keyword_lowercase_analyzer",
                    "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Querying:

```
{
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "AAA.BBB",
            "fields": [
              "A",
              "B",
              "C"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "D": {
              "query": "AAA.BBB",
              "operator": "or"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": [
      "<em>"
    ],
    "post_tags": [
      "</em>"
    ],
    "fields": {
      "A": {},
      "B": {},
      "C": {},
      "D": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Note:

- I used `with_positions_offsets` for faster highlighting terms. Yon can refer here for more info: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html
- You can install `inquisitor` plugin to test analyzers, it'll help you find out the problems like this.

Comment: The answer to every "why" above is "cause I don't know what I'm doing" :)  Thanks so much for your help.... worked first time, as is. It is much appreciated.

Comment: I only regret that I have but one upvote to give for your answer.